# Exercise 6.1 from ANSI C book - getword function

Tags: c, binary-search

I have a following exercise from ANSI C book:

> Exercise 6.1. Our version of getword does not properly handle
>   underscores, string constants, comments, or preprocessor control
>   lines. Write a better version.

Here's my improved version of getword function and code that test if it works:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100
#define MAXWORD 100
#define NKEYS (sizeof keytab / sizeof(keytab[0]))

int buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

struct key {
    char * word;
    int count;
} keytab[] = {
        { "#define", 0 },
        { "#elif", 0 },
        { "#else", 0 },
        { "#endif", 0 },
        { "#error", 0 },
        { "#if", 0 },
        { "#ifdef", 0 },
        { "#ifndef", 0 },
        { "#include", 0 },
        { "#line", 0 },
        { "#pragma", 0 },
        { "auto", 0 },
        { "break", 0 },
        { "case", 0 },
        { "char", 0 },
        { "const", 0 },
        { "continue", 0 },
        { "default", 0 },
        { "do", 0 },
        { "double", 0 },
        { "else", 0 },
        { "enum", 0 },
        { "extern", 0 },
        { "float", 0 },
        { "for", 0 },
        { "goto", 0 },
        { "if", 0 },
        { "int", 0 },
        { "long", 0 },
        { "register", 0 },
        { "return", 0 },
        { "short", 0 },
        { "signed", 0 },
        { "sizeof", 0 },
        { "static", 0 },
        { "struct", 0 },
        { "switch", 0 },
        { "typedef", 0 },
        { "union", 0 },
        { "unsigned", 0 },
        { "void", 0 },
        { "volatile", 0 },
        { "while", 0 },
};

int getword(char *, int);
int binsearch(char *, struct key *, int);
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int main(void) {
    int n,  c;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    while ((c = getword(word, MAXWORD)) != EOF) {
//        printf("getword(word, MAXWORD) = %c %d\n", c, c);
//        printf("word = %s\n", word);
        if (isalpha(word[0]) || word[0] == '_' || word[0] == '#') {
            if ((n = binsearch(word, keytab, NKEYS)) >= 0) {
                keytab[n].count++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (n = 0; n < NKEYS; n++)
        if (keytab[n].count > 0)
            printf("%4d %s\n",
                   keytab[n].count, keytab[n].word);
    return 0;
}

int getch(void) {
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) {
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}

int getword(char * word, int lim) {
    int c;
    char * w = word;
    static int last;
    while (isblank(c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    if (last == '/' && c == '/') {
        while (c = getch() != '\n')
            ;
        return c;
    }
    if (last == '/' && c == '*') {
        x:
        while (c = getch() != '*')
            ;
        if (c = getch() == '/')
            return c;
        else
            goto x;
    }
    if (c == '\'') {
        while (c = getch() != '\'')
            ;
        return c;
    }
    if (c == '\"') {
        while (c = getch() != '\"')
            ;
        return c;
    }
    if (!isalpha(c) && c != '_' && c != '#') {
        *w = '\0';
        last = c;
        return c;
    }
    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++) {
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch()) && *w != '_') {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    }
    *w = '\0';
    last = word[0];
    return word[0];
}

int binsearch(char * word, struct key tab[], int n) {
    int cond;
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if ((cond = strcmp(word, tab[mid].word)) < 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (cond > 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

What are your opinions about my solution? Is it a correct approach? Is this code enough fast?

Answer (score 1):

- The `last` logic is quite hard to trace, and it is prone to bugs. Consider `/* ... */*`. Once the code reached the closing `/`, it returns, but `last` is not updated, and remains `/`, so the next `*` is still treated as a beginning of a comment.
- Handling of string constants has a definite problem: it doesn't account for an escaped quote char in the middle of the string (e.g. `"aaa\"bbb"`).

Combining the two above observations, I strongly recommend to revisit the design, and realize few more functions, such as `get_line_comment`, `get_c_comment`, `get_quoted_string` etc.

- No word in `keytab` starts with an underscore. You don't need to go into `binsearch` in that case.
- The preprocessor directive may not appear in the middle of the line. I am not sure if a directive in such case should be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this:

```
struct key {
    char * word;
    int count;
} keytab[] = {
        { "#define", 0 },
        { "#elif", 0 },
...
```

Separate out the definition of the `struct` from the declaration of the variable. This is very hard to read, unexpected, and smacks of cleverness for cleverness' sake. It also saves you all of maybe 10-15 characters at the cost of readability.